# Affine map of single qubit quantum operations

Tags: linear-algebra, affine-geometry, quantum-computation

In my reference, [Page 375, Chapter 8, Quantum Computation and Quantum Information by Nielsen and Chuang](http://mmrc.amss.cas.cn/tlb/201702/W020170224608149940643.pdf), it is given that

[image: af1]
[image: af2]

---

The Pauli matrices, along with the identity matrix $I$, form an orthonormal basis for the Hilbert space of all $2\times 2$ complex matrices, $\mathbb{M}_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{C})$.

$\therefore$ The operators $E_i$ can be written in the form,
$$
E_i=\alpha_i I+\sum_{k=1}^3a_{ik}\sigma_k
$$
$$
\rho=\frac{I+\vec{r}.\vec{\sigma}}{2}=\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}1+r_z&r_x-ir_y\\r_x+ir_y&1-r_z\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $\vec{r}=(r_x,r_y,r_z)$ and $\vec{\sigma}=(\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\sigma_3)=\Big(\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&-i\\i&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}\Big)$

The Pauli matrices satisfy the following properties,
$$
\sigma_j\sigma_k=\delta_{jk}I+i\epsilon_{jkl}\sigma_l\\
\sigma_1^2=\sigma_2^2=\sigma_3^2=-i\sigma_1\sigma_2\sigma_3=I
$$

\begin{align}
\mathcal{E}&(\rho)=\sum_l E_l\rho E_l^\dagger=\frac{I+\sum_l E_l(\vec{r}.\vec{\sigma})E_l^\dagger}{2}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\bigg[I+\sum_l\Big[ \Big(\alpha_lI+\sum_{j=1}^3a_{lj}\sigma_j\Big)\Big(\sum_{k=1}^3r_k\sigma_k\Big)\Big(\alpha_l^*I+\sum_{p=1}^3a^*_{lp}\sigma_p\Big) \Big]\bigg]\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\bigg[I+\sum_l\Big[ |\alpha_l|^2\sum_{k=1}^3r_k\sigma_k+\alpha_l\sum_{k=1}^3r_k\sigma_k\sum_{p=1}^3a_{lp}^*\sigma_p+\alpha_l^*\sum_{j=1}^3a_{lj}\sigma_j \sum_{k=1}^3r_k\sigma_k+\sum_{j=1}^3a_{lj}\sigma_j\sum_{k=1}^3r_k\sigma_k\sum_{p=1}^3a_{lp}^*\sigma_p \Big]\bigg]\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\bigg[I+\sum_l\Big[ |\alpha_l|^2\sum_{k=1}^3r_k\sigma_k+\alpha_l\sum_{k=1}^3\sum_{p=1}^3r_ka_{lp}^*\sigma_k\sigma_p+\alpha_l^*\sum_{j=1}^3\sum_{k=1}^3r_ka_{lj}\sigma_j \sigma_k+\sum_{j=1}^3\sum_{k=1}^3\sum_{p=1}^3r_ka_{lj}a_{lp}^*\sigma_j\sigma_k\sigma_p \Big]\bigg]\\
\end{align}

I think I need to rearrange this in the form $\mathcal{E}(\rho)=\frac{I+(M\vec{r}+\vec{c}).\vec{\sigma}}{2}$ to obtain $M_{jk}=\sum_{l}\bigg[ a_{lj}a_{lk}^*+a_{lj}^*a_{lk}+(|a_l|^2-\sum_p a_{lp}a_{lp}^*)+i\sum_p\epsilon_{jkp}(\alpha_la_{lp}^*-\alpha_l^*a_{lp}) \bigg]$ and $c_{_k}=2i\sum_l\sum_{jp}\epsilon_{jkp}a_{lj}a_{lp}^*$. How do I proceed further and obtain the required expression for $M_{jk}$ and $c_k$ ?

This is asked in [Affine Map of the Bloch sphere](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/9799/affine-map-of-the-bloch-sphere) but it does not contain any solution.

This is also given as in [Exercise 6.1, Page 338, Principles of Quantum Computation II by Giuliano Benenti and Giulio Casat](http://www-reynal.ensea.fr/docs/iq/PrinciplesOfQuantumComputation2.pdf)

Comment: I could also find a similar post, https://faculty.iisertvm.ac.in/shaji/IISER_Home/Teaching_files/lecture20.pdf, which seems to be in the same context.